# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000

Tags: tex-core, input, capacity, stack

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\else
  \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}\fi

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[scale=0.775]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\addtolength{\parskip}{6pt}

\def\firstname{Max}
\def\familyname{Mustermann}
\def\FileAuthor{\firstname~\familyname}
\def\FileTitle{\firstname~\familyname's Bewerbungsschreiben}
\def\FileSubject{Bewerbungsschreiben}
\def\FileKeyWords{\firstname~\familyname, Bewerbungsschreiben}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\hyphenation{ins-be-son-de-re}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{tt}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex,pdfborder=0,breaklinks,baseurl=http://,pdfpagemode=None,pdfstartview=XYZ,pdfstartpage=1]{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{
    pdfauthor   = \FileAuthor,%
    pdftitle    = \FileTitle,%
    pdfsubject  = \FileSubject,%
    pdfkeywords = \FileKeyWords,%
    pdfcreator  = \LaTeX,%
    pdfproducer = \LaTeX}
\else
  \usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}
\fi

\definecolor{firstnamecolor}{RGB}{125,85,85}
\definecolor{familynamecolor}{RGB}{138,74,57}
\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0}

\begin{document}
\sffamily   % for use with a résumé using sans serif fonts;
%\rmfamily  % for use with a résumé using serif fonts;
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.6\textwidth}
    \raggedleft%
    {\bfseries {\color{firstnamecolor}\firstname}~{\color{familynamecolor}\familyname}}\\[.35ex]
    \small\itshape%
    Musterstraße 08/15\\
    8010 Graz\\[.35ex]
    \Mobilefone~+43 123 45 789 90\\
    \Letter~\href{mailto:max@mustermann.at}{max@mustermann.at}
\end{minipage}\\[0.5em]
%
{\color{firstnamecolor}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    % {\bfseries {\color{firstnamecolor}
    \vspace*{1em}
    Musterfirma\\[.35ex]
    % }}
    \small%
    Hans-im-Glück-Gasse 47 Top 11\\
    8010 Graz
\end{minipage}
%
\hfill
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
    \raggedleft % US style
    \today
    %April 6, 2006 % US informal style
    %05/04/2006 % UK formal style
\end{minipage}\\[1em]
\raggedright

{\bfseries \color{familynamecolor}Bewerbung als Kasperl}\\[1.5em]

Sehr geehrter Herr DI Dr. Pezi,\\[1em]
%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  
%Yours sincerely,\\[2em] % if the opening is "Dear Mr(s) Doe,"
Mit freundlichen Grüßen,\\[3em] % if the opening is "Dear Sir or Madam,"
%
%\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{signature_blue}\\
{\bfseries \firstname~\familyname}\\
%
\vfill%
{\slshape \bfseries Bewerbungsunterlagen}\\
% {\slshape Curriculum Vit\ae{}}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this error?

I attached the file.

Thanks!

```
enter code here
```

Comment: unrelated but you should remove the `\ifpdf`  tests, just ise `\usepackage{graphicx}`  with no option and let it choose the correct option iteslf, similarly for `hyperrref`

Comment: remove `\usepackage{ngerman}`. It is unneeded (you are using babel too) and breaks stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Item 1 in the list below solves the main problem. But, please, also consider the other items.

1. You can't use both the `ngerman` package and `babel`
2. The `ngerman` package is obsolete
3. The `ifpdf` test for `graphicx` is not needed
4. Remove the `pdftex` option for `color`
5. `utf8x` is obsolete
6. There is no need for `inputenc` if your file is UTF-8 encoded
7. Don't use `\def`
8. Separate package loading and settings whenever possible
9. If I ask TeX to hyphenate `insbesondere` in German, the answer is `ins-be-son-de-re`, so there's no need to set it
10. The appropriate value for `pdfpagemode` is `UseNone`, not `None`

```
\newcommand\firstname{Max}
\newcommand\familyname{Mustermann}
\newcommand\FileAuthor{\firstname~\familyname}
\newcommand\FileTitle{\firstname~\familyname's Bewerbungsschreiben}
\newcommand\FileSubject{Bewerbungsschreiben}
\newcommand\FileKeyWords{\firstname~\familyname, Bewerbungsschreiben}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[scale=0.775]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}

\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex,]{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{
    breaklinks,
    baseurl=http://,
    pdfpagemode=UseNone,
    pdfstartview=XYZ,
    pdfstartpage=1,
    pdfauthor   = \FileAuthor,
    pdftitle    = \FileTitle,
    pdfsubject  = \FileSubject,
    pdfkeywords = \FileKeyWords,
    pdfcreator  = \LaTeX,
    pdfproducer = \LaTeX
  }
\else
  \usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\addtolength{\parskip}{6pt}

\urlstyle{tt}


\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

%\hyphenation{ins-be-son-de-re}

\definecolor{firstnamecolor}{RGB}{125,85,85}
\definecolor{familynamecolor}{RGB}{138,74,57}



\begin{document}

\sffamily   % for use with a résumé using sans serif fonts;
%\rmfamily  % for use with a résumé using serif fonts;
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.6\textwidth}
    \raggedleft%
    {\bfseries {\color{firstnamecolor}\firstname}~{\color{familynamecolor}\familyname}}\\[.35ex]
    \small\itshape%
    Musterstraße 08/15\\
    8010 Graz\\[.35ex]
    \Mobilefone~+43 123 45 789 90\\
    \Letter~\href{mailto:max@mustermann.at}{max@mustermann.at}
\end{minipage}\\[0.5em]
%
{\color{firstnamecolor}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    % {\bfseries {\color{firstnamecolor}
    \vspace*{1em}
    Musterfirma\\[.35ex]
    % }}
    \small%
    Hans-im-Glück-Gasse 47 Top 11\\
    8010 Graz
\end{minipage}
%
\hfill
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
    \raggedleft % US style
    \today
    %April 6, 2006 % US informal style
    %05/04/2006 % UK formal style
\end{minipage}\\[1em]
\raggedright

{\bfseries \color{familynamecolor}Bewerbung als Kasperl}\\[1.5em]

Sehr geehrter Herr DI Dr. Pezi,\\[1em]
%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  
%Yours sincerely,\\[2em] % if the opening is "Dear Mr(s) Doe,"
Mit freundlichen Grüßen,\\[3em] % if the opening is "Dear Sir or Madam,"
%
%\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{signature_blue}\\
{\bfseries \firstname~\familyname}\\
%
\vfill%
{\slshape \bfseries Bewerbungsunterlagen}\\
% {\slshape Curriculum Vit\ae{}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just eliminate `\usepackage{ngerman}` from your document, and it will compile.